# Does an unlimited duration Polymorph Any Object give back a lost limb until the target decides to resume its normal form?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, polymorph, duration

Most polymorph spells are temporary, but suppose the target gets polymorphed from an "armless" human to an elf. The spell [Polymorph Any Object](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polymorph-any-object/) would last indefinitely: would the target then keep the new arm permanently (or at least until it decides to be a human again?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.** Polymorph any object can give legs to a mermaid or turn a corpse full of daggers (an inanimate object) into a living treant; arming the otherwise armless is peanuts by comparison.